# Coral vine tuber not showing any signs of growing back

Tags: vines

I have a small coral vine tuber which I found while digging up an old pot in which it used to grow a year back but is no more now. I had planted the tuber over a month back in another pot and it has not yet shown any signs of growing back. I love the vine and really want it to grow back as many butterflies would visit it when it flowers. Would somebody please suggest what to do? I water it when the topsoil seems dry and it is placed in filtered sunlight. I live in India and it's monsoon season here so not a lot of sunlight. Thanks!!!